# Syntax error trying to insert an SQL clause

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error:

```
 CREATE TABLE `libro`
 (
 `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `autor_id` INTEGER(11),
 `titulo` VARCHAR(255),
 `paginas` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 INDEX `libro_FI_1` (`autor_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `libro_FK_1`
 FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`)
 REFERENCES `autor` (`id`)
 )Type=InnoDB
[propel-sql-exec] SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Type=InnoDB' at line 12
```

Any idea?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Is it the commas after `PRIMARY KEY` and `INDEX`, or the lack of commas after `CONSTRAINT` and `FOREIGN KEY`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ENGINE` instead of `Type`

```
 CREATE TABLE `libro`
 (
  `id` INTEGER  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `autor_id` INTEGER(11),
  `titulo` VARCHAR(255),
  `paginas` VARCHAR(255)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `libro_FI_1` (`autor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `libro_FK_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`)
  REFERENCES `autor` (`id`)
 )ENGINE=InnoDB
```